# display: none on body tag in chrome does not hide background

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a site where I set the background image and color of the body tag via CSS. I hide it with the inline style `display: none;` so that optimizely has time to run and do any customizations without causing a flicker. This has worked till recently when the flicker came back but we haven't changed anything that seems related. I was debugging it and saw that in Chrome (Version 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit)) the background image and color are still displayed even though the body is `display: none;`. In firefox, safari, and IE11 the background is not displayed.

Here is some code to illustrate the issue:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <style>.background { background-color: red; }</style>
   </head>
   <body class="background" style="display: none;"></body>
</html>
```

I googled but couldn't figure out why. Any ideas?

To be clear the question is about why this happens on the body tag. I am open to alternate ways to hide the background image but wont consider them the answer.

Comment: its because you tried in body tag.. try for separate div, it ll work...http://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/WQogvB?editors=110

Comment: Try giving `html{ display:none;}` in your CSS.

Comment: Maybe will be better to add a class like .default with default set of css properties `background-color: #fff; color: #000;`

Comment: Just asking why are you doing this? I mean hiding the body. Why?

Comment: @G.L.P - yeah I saw it worked on divs and I know I can do a work around with that but I want to know why it doesn't work on body.

Comment: @Stafox - thanks that is a reasonable work around.

Comment: @divy3993 - to prevent a flicker that will occur if optimizely changes the background color/image (which it is in my case). The background will show blue and then optimizely will run and make it white.

Comment: Ok, so are you sure using `html { display:none; }` isn't working. http://jsfiddle.net/L3gfr8of/

Comment: @divy3993 - yeah I see that setting display none on the html tag works. I had a test earlier where I thought it failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [W3 CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/colors.html#q2),

> For HTML documents, however, we recommend that authors specify the
>   background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element. User
>   agents should observe the following precedence rules to fill in the
>   background: **if the value of the 'background' property for the HTML
>   element is different from 'transparent' then use it, else use the
>   value of the 'background' property for the BODY element.** If the
>   resulting value is 'transparent', the rendering is undefined.

According to this, if you set a `background-color` or `background-image` on the `body`, but don't set a `background-color` other than `transparent` on the `html`, then the `html` will use the `body`'s background. So when you hide the `body`, the `html` will still be using it's background.

**DEMO**

```js
var hideButton = $('#hide-body');
var toggleBGButton = $('#toggle-html-bg');

hideButton.on('click', function() {$('body').hide()} );
toggleBGButton.on('click', function() {$('html').toggleClass('bg')} );
```

```css
html {
  background-color: transparent;
}

html.bg {
  background-color: orange;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
  background-color: blue;
}

body.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hide-body">Hide body</button>
<button id="toggle-html-bg">Toggle &lt;html&gt; background-color</button>
```

Comment: @bygrace If you set a `background-color` or `background-image` on the `body`, but don't set a `background-color` other than `transparent` on the `html`, then the `html` will use the `body`'s background.  So when you hide the `body`, the `html` will still be using it's background.

Comment: @bygrace Great! I imagine there's a good reason for them doing this, but I honestly can't think of it... :)

Comment: Yeah I am wondering why Chrome seems to be the only browser respecting that too... :)